# pytesseract No such file or directory OSError no 2

Tags: python, subprocess, tesseract, python-tesseract

When I use pytesseract's `image_to_string` function, it throws `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. The full error message is [here](https://pastebin.com/4bCHnrd1). The same happens when I use `subprocess.call(["tesseract", "inputfile.png", "outputfile"])`. Every other suggestion says that I need to install tesseract, and be able to use it on the command line. However, I did that beforehand, and can use tesseract from the command line by running `tesseract inputfile.png outputfile`, and this works fine. The issue is that python subprocess won't support tesseract, even though it's installed and accessible from the command line. I'm on macOS, by the way.

Comment: I've experienced a similar problem (though not on Mac). Rebooting fixed the issue.

Comment: @Rawing rebooting didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue. I had to add `shell=True` as an argument in `subprocess.call`. This was not supported by pytesseract, so I created my own module. No idea why this works.